# Method is not abstract and does not override method

Tags: java

I just posted about abstract methods and I think this was the reason it wouldn't compile.

super class

```
public abstract class Monster extends GameCharacter {

   public abstract int getxP();      
   protected int monsterXP;

     public Monster(String name, int health, int attack, int xp) {
         super(name, health, attack);
         this.monsterXP = xp;
     }
```

my subclass

```
public class Goblin extends Monster {

    public Goblin(String name, int health, int attack, int xp){
        super(name, health, attack, xp);
    }

    public Goblin(){
        this("Goblin", 70, 15, 2);
    }
}
```

> error:Goblin is not abstract and does not override abstract method
>   getxP() in Monster

so I'm not sure what's going on here the code is the same for the super class GameCharacter in respects to constructor. I don't see why xp is different than the name, health, and attack.

for clarity how I arranged my super class

```
public abstract class GameCharacter {

    public abstract String getName();
    public abstract int getHealth();
    public abstract int getAttackPower();

    protected String gameCharacterName;
    protected int gameCharacterHealth;
    protected int gameCharacterAttack;

    public GameCharacter(String name, int health, int attack){
        this.gameCharacterName = name;
        this.gameCharacterHealth = health;
        this.gameCharacterAttack = attack;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to override `getxP();` in `Goblin` If you extend an `abstract` class you must `OVERRIDE` all of its `ABSTRACT` methods.

Comment: I think that the error is self explanatory, which part of the compilation-error message didn't you understand ? "error:Goblin is not abstract and does not override abstract method getxP() in Monster"

Answer (score 2):

So `GameCharacter` is an `abstract class` and has `abstract` methods.

And `Monster` is an `abstract class` and has `abstract` methods.

And Goblin is a concrete `class` and should implement any `abstract` methods that have not been implemented by a superclass.  I suspect that `getxP()` just happens to be the first one the compiler came across as missing and failed after that.  If you implement `getxP()`, the other missing methods should also cause compilation errors, assuming they haven't been implemented in some code we don't see here.

To answer in code form, `Goblin` needs to look like this:

```
public class Goblin extends Monster {

    public Goblin(String name, int health, int attack, int xp){
        super(name, health, attack, xp);
    }

    public Goblin(){
        this("Goblin", 70, 15, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public int getxP() {
        return monsterXP;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return gameCharacterName;
    }

    @Override
    public int getHealth() {
        return gameCharacterHealth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAttackPower() {
        return gameCharacterAttack;
    }
}
```

However, as @Dromlius's answer suggests, you should probably be implementing these in their respective classes.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but it still had the same error. I did as @Dromlius said though and made it non abstract. It seems to work now

Answer (score 1):

Making a method abstract means that you are going to implement it in a subclass. In your case you declare your get-methods as abstract, which does little sense in your scenario.

Instead of writing:

```
public abstract int getXX();
```

Write:

```
public int getXX() {
   return XX;
}
```

It does not complain about attack,  health ect in your Monster-class, because you declared the Monster-class abstract as well, basicly saying: "I know there are abstract methods in this class (partially inherited from GameCharacter), but I will implement them in the next non-abstract subclass (in your case Goblin).

If you want to keep your methods abstract, you will have to implement all abstract methods of all abstract superclasses (GameChar & Monster) in your non-abstract subclass (Goblin)

Comment: thank you that really helped. Thank you for explanation as well.